# how can I do if many class inherit one interface with Ninject.Extensions.Conventions

Tags: ninject, ninject-conventions

In my item,there are multi class inherit one interface, and many interface like this.
for example,class A|B|C inherit interface Ilog, class F|E|G inherit interface IData, and class H|I|J inherit IBase, and so on. now ,I want bind All Interface use Ninject.Extensions.Conventions,how can I do. if use conventions can't do it,please tell me the best way to do it. and I want somebody tell me how use Ninject.Extensions.Conventions in Item,don't tell me the concrete syntex,I want to know how to organize my class and Interface let bind interface easier,Thank you for your help!
code example like this:

```
public interface Ilog
{
  //... ...
}

public class A:IIlog
{
  //... ...
}

public class B:ILog
{
  //... ...
}

public class C:ILog
{
  //... ...
}

public interface IData
{
  //... ...
}

public class H:IData
{
   //... ...
}
public class E:IData
{
//... ...
}

public class G:IData
{
  //... ...
}


public interface IBase
{
 //... ...
}

public class H:IBase
{
 //... ...
}

public class I:IBase
{
 //... ...
}

public class J:IBase
{
 //... ...
}
```

now,I want resolve interface Ilog to A,IData to E,IBase to H,how can I Do with Ninject.Extensions.Conventions? if many interface like this,how can I do?

Comment: please specify more exactly what the desired outcome is. To what interface/type etc. should the types be bound? Also according to SO rules you should go into more details what you've already tried. Provided with the information you've given herein, I'm unsure to whether you should actually change the organization of your classes and interfaces.

Comment: Have you had a look at this site: [Ninject Conventions Overview](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/wiki/Overview)?